# Using XSL (without position()) to colour alternate rows in a table

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to colour alternate rows in a table, which is being created from an XML file. I am doing this using XSL.

I have tried setting the background-color based on `position() mod 2 = 0`, and the position of every row is always 1. Please see below for a sample of three rows of the table I am creating.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:ns2="sample:thing:code:ACDDMMessage">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="default-page"
                page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="0.8cm"
                margin-bottom="0.3cm" margin-left="1.0cm" margin-right="1.0cm">
                <!-- where the content goes -->
                <fo:region-body margin-top="0.5cm" margin-bottom="0.5cm" />
                <!-- header -->
                <fo:region-before extent="0.5cm" />
                <!-- footer -->
                <fo:region-after extent="0.5cm" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="default-page" force-page-count="no-force" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:call-template name="CallPrinDetails">
                </xsl:call-template>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="CallPrinDetails">
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-style="none" background-repeat="repeat" white-space-collapse="false">
<fo:table-column column-width="8.0cm" />
<fo:table-column column-width="5.0cm" />
<fo:table-column column-width="6.0cm" />
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row border-top="solid #4A7EBB" line-height="20pt">
            <fo:table-cell border-style="none" background-repeat="repeat" display-align="center">
                <fo:block  text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                    <xsl:if test="/ns2:ACDDMMessage/InstrumentLongName != ''">
                        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Security</fo:inline>
                    </xsl:if>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border-style="none" background-repeat="repeat" display-align="center">
                <fo:block  text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                    <xsl:if test="/ns2:ACDDMMessage/ExternalInstrumentRef != ''">
                        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Market Identifier </fo:inline>
                        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">(<xsl:value-of select="/ns2:ACDDMMessage/SecurityRefType"/>)</fo:inline>
                    </xsl:if>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border-style="none" background-repeat="repeat" display-align="center">
                <fo:block  text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                    <xsl:if test="/ns2:ACDDMMessage/SecurityType != ''">
                        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Security Type</fo:inline>
                    </xsl:if>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <xsl:for-each select="/ns2:ACDDMMessage/Charge">
            <xsl:if test="ChargeLevyType = 'PTM'">
                <fo:table-row background-color="#997FB6" line-height="20pt">
                    <fo:table-cell border-style="none" background-repeat="repeat" display-align="center">
                        <fo:block  text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                            <xsl:text>PTM Levy</xsl:text>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ChargeLevyInstrument"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell background-repeat="repeat">
                        <fo:block  text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                            <xsl:call-template name="FormatANumber">
                                <xsl:with-param name="NumberInput"> 
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ChargeLevyQuantity"/>
                                </xsl:with-param>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="ChargeLevyType = 'SDRT'">
                <fo:table-row background-color="#F5844C" line-height="20pt">
                    <fo:table-cell border-style="none" background-repeat="repeat" display-align="center">
                        <fo:block  text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                            <xsl:text>Stamp Duty</xsl:text>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ChargeLevyInstrument"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell background-repeat="repeat">
                        <fo:block  text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                            <xsl:call-template name="FormatANumber">
                                <xsl:with-param name="NumberInput"> 
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ChargeLevyQuantity"/>
                                </xsl:with-param>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <fo:table-row line-height="20pt">
            <fo:table-cell background-repeat="repeat">
                <fo:block  text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/ns2:ACDDMMessage/InstrumentLongName"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell background-repeat="repeat">
                <fo:block  text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/ns2:ACDDMMessage/ExternalInstrumentRef" />
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/ns2:ACDDMMessage/Sedol"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell background-repeat="repeat">
                <fo:block  text-align="left" font-size="11pt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/ns2:ACDDMMessage/SecurityType"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried setting up a variable at the top, and choosing the attribute based on `position()`, but neither of these methods work.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions, as this is sending me a bit mad.

EDIT: Here is a sample of the input XML:

```
<ns2:ACDDMMessage xmlns:ns2="sample:thing:code:ACDDMMessage">
    <InstrumentLongName>ABC Ord. Shares</InstrumentLongName>
    <ExternalInstrumentRef>GB1234567890</ExternalInstrumentRef>
    <TradeReference>0000000000071</TradeReference>
    <Sedol>ASEDOLCODE</Sedol>
    <SecurityType>Equity</SecurityType>
    <PrimaryQuantity>ECP1</PrimaryQuantity>
    <AddressLine1>123 Confirms Lane</AddressLine1>
</ns2:ACDDMMessage>
```

Comment: `position()` depends critically on exactly which nodes you `select`-ed with the `apply-templates` or `for-each` that caused this code to fire.  We need to see a sample of the _input_ XML, and the portion of your stylesheet where you select the nodes for processing, in order to be able to suggest why `position()` doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks @IanRoberts. I have edited the question to add some more details.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Your stylesheet doesn't do any iteration over unknown numbers of elements - you're always creating a fixed set of rows in the same order - so there's no need for anything fancy, you can just hard-code the row colours.

Comment: Hi @IanRoberts - In the case where there is no value for `PrimaryQuantity`, or another field name, the row is not created, and so the alternate rows are no longer different colours.

Comment: In the case where there is no value for `PrimaryQuantity` the stylesheet you've given in the question _will_ still create a `fo:table-row`, there's just no text within the cell.

Comment: I have edited the code so that the for-each which may have 0, 1 or more entries is included. Sorry for missing this out initially.